Android Compose Volley Post Request with parameters
I need make request in Android Kotlin Compose with Volley.
The request is in POST method with 2 parameters: email and token.
I made a simple request but i don't know how to add parameters.
Can someone help me?
Here
fun PostVolleyRequest(
    context: Context,
    result: MutableState<String>
) {

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val email = "mail@gmail.com"

    val url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/logged/accedi"
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(
        Method.POST,
        url,
        { response -> result.value = response },
        { println("That didn't work!") }
        )   


    queue.add(stringRequest)
}


Also have a look at Retrofit, it allows sending network requests with less code and tends to be simpler to use.

you can override the getParams() method in the StringRequest class.
fun PostVolleyRequest(
    context: Context,
    result: MutableState<String>
) {
    
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val email = "mail@gmail.com"
    val token = "your_token" // replace with your token
    
    val url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/logged/accedi"
    val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Method.POST, url, 
        { response -> result.value = response }, { println("That didn't work!") }) {

        override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
            val params = HashMap<String, String>()
            params["email"] = email
            params["token"] = token
            return params
        }
    }
    
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}

